# Rust TT muncher has infinite recursion

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a TT muncher to create a nested hash map structure. The basic type definition is

```
type Object = HashMap<String, Node>;

enum Node {
    Terminal(String),
    Nested(Object),
}
```

I know that I can manually create these objects:

```
let mut x: Object = HashMap::new();

x.insert("foo".into(), Node::Terminal("bar".into()));
x.insert("bing".into(), {
    let mut bing = HashMap::new();
    bing.insert("bar".into(), Node::Terminal("baz".into()));
    Node::Nested(bing)
});
```

And this does generate the expected structure

```
{
    "bing": Nested(
        {
            "bar": Terminal(
                "baz"
            )
        }
    ),
    "foo": Terminal(
        "bar"
    )
}
```

But I have a few large literals in this format, and I'd prefer to use a less ugly syntax, so I'm trying to make a macro. Here's a minimum example of what I think should work:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

type Object = HashMap<String, Node>;


#[derive(Debug)]
enum Node {
    Terminal(String),
    Nested(Object),
}


macro_rules! obj {
    {
        $($tt:tt)*
    } => {
        {
            let map = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();

            obj!(@parse; map; ($($tt)*));

            map
        }
    };
    (@parse; $name:ident; ()) => {};
    (@parse; $name:ident; ($key:expr => $value:expr, $($tail:tt)*)) => {
        $name.insert($key.into(), Node::Terminal($value.into()));
        obj!(@parse; $name; ($($tail)*));
    };
    (@parse; $name:ident; ($key:expr => $value:block, $($tail:tt)*)) => {
        $name.insert($key.into(), Node::Nested(obj!{$value}));
        obj!(@parse; $name; ($($tail)*));
    };
}

fn main() {
    let x: Object = obj!{
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bing" => {
            "bar" => "baz",
        },
    };

    println!("{:#?}", x);
}
```

This does not work, I get a recursion error when I try to compile it:

```
error: recursion limit reached while expanding the macro `obj`
  --> src/main.rs:22:13
   |
22 |               obj!(@parse; map; ($($tt)*));
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
40 |       let x: Object = obj!{
   |  _____________________-
41 | |         "foo" => "bar",
42 | |         "bing" => {
43 | |             "bar" => "baz",
44 | |         },
45 | |     };
   | |_____- in this macro invocation
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
```

I've tried bumping the recursion limit way up, and it does not terminate. What am I missing in my macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the first rule matches literally *anything*.  There's no way for it to *not* recurse.

When writing macros, you need to write your rules from most-specific to least-specific.